# value count for an attribute from the column when there are multiple values for the attribute

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, count

I a trying to count and visualize netflix dataset depending on the country column, but when checked the data set I found there are some rows in the column that contains multiple values for country such as the
below one;
[image]

following is the code to count

```
country_count=joint_data['country'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)
country_count=pd.DataFrame(country_count)
topcountries=country_count[0:11]  
topcountries.shape
```

so  I wanted to count those rows as individual countries to get the proper count of countries.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `country` column by `,` and then `.explode()`. Next step is `.groupby()`:

```
df = df['country'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).explode().to_frame()
print( df.groupby('country').agg('size') )
```

Prints:

```
country
Austria           1
Canada            1
Germany           1
India             2
United Kingdom    1
United States     1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compile all possible values from your `'country'` column, make a set out of it and create new columns for each.

Then you can iterate your rows and fill in if the column is inside this rows `'country'`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"country":["A,B,C","A,D,E,F","G"]})
print(df)

df[[*sorted(set(','.join(df["country"]).split(",")))]] = 0

for row in df.iterrows():
    row[1][ [*(row[1]["country"].split(","))]] = 1
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   country     A     B     C     D     E     F     G
0    A,B,C     1     1     1  None  None  None  None
1  A,D,E,F     1  None  None     1     1     1  None
2        G  None  None  None  None  None  None     1
```

---

If you'd rather have `0` instead of `None`use `df.fillna(0, inplace=True)` to convert them:

```
# 0 instead of None
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
print(df)

# print sums
for c in df.columns:
    if c == "country":
        continue
    print(f"{c} {df[c].sum()}")
```

Output:

```
   country  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
0    A,B,C  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
1  A,D,E,F  1  0  0  1  1  1  0
2        G  0  0  0  0  0  0  1

A 2
B 1
C 1
D 1
E 1
F 1
G 1
```